# How can I post data in request payload instead of a as form data

Tags: api, robotframework

I have a api which requires 2 input as a form data but i want a request body to pass those two vale ..

problem here is I'm using Rest Instance library with robot framework , which doesn't support handling form data

Comment: How is the form data sent in the API? Is it part of the body or the params? Include what you have already tried in the question. Probably the structure of the API might also help in better understanding your problem.

Comment: as a pram .we have no request body

Answer (score 0):

If you mean it passed in query string like this:

```
mydomain.com/test.html?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

See [RequestKeyword](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/) and its **Post Request** keyword with argument *params* that receive dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for helping but how can I pass a file path here plus  I need to use Rest Instance Library for schema validation too .. Do we have any way to handle this by using Rest Instance lib ?

Answer (score 0):

Append the params to the end of the URL of the API like this:

```
Post  /api/endpoint?param1=param1value&param2=pamar2value
```

> **Note:** I'm assuming you're using [RestInstance Library](https://asyrjasalo.github.io/RESTinstance/#Post)

You can also use the [HTTPRequests Library](https://github.com/asyrjasalo/RESTinstance/) as mentioned in the other answer by @drFunJohn.

Comment: Thanks for helping but I need to use Rest Instance Library for schema validation too .. Do we have any way to handle this by using Rest Instance lib ?

Comment: The code I have written is for RestInstance library only. Just append the params at the end of the api endpoint like I mentioned in the answer: `Post  /api/endpoint?param1=param1value&param2=pamar2value
`

Comment: can we pass form data as a part of uri ?

Comment: Ideally, you should be able to do that. Have you tried it and ran into any issues?

Comment: yup getting 500 as i have post request where I need to pass

Comment: I tried with the `RequestsLibrary` and it works completely fine. This is the same format that your web browser would use to send a request to that API. Can you share your code snippet?